# How to Separate commands on save

Tags: vb.net

This code is working but now i want if all the textboxes(Tbxs) are filled but the picturebox (Pbx1) contains no image the Msgbox to show"Now Load Photo"

```
If Tbx1.Text = "" Or Tbx2.Text = "" Or Tbx3.Text = "" Or Tbx4.Text = ""  Or Pbx1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Kindly Fill the Blank Cells", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

How will i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
    If (Tbx1.Text = "" Or Tbx2.Text = "" Or Tbx3.Text = "" Or Tbx4.Text = "") And Pbx1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Kindly Fill the Blank Cells", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf CheckFilled({Tbx1, Tbx2, Tbx3, Tbx4}) And Pbx1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Now Load Photo", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End If

Private Function CheckFilled(Tb As TextBox()) As Boolean
    Dim retVal As Boolean = True

    For Each t As TextBox In Tb
        If t.Text.Length <= 0 Then retVal = False
    Next

    Return retVal
End Function
```

Comment: this code is almost functioning just that i changed two textboxes to comboboxes. Kindly redo  the code for me and replace Tbx3 & Tbx4 to be Cbx1 & Cbx2 as the new comboboxes.